# CSS headline centered with background which is just as long as the text

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this:

[image: Screenshot]

So I tried this: https://jsfiddle.net/bv68ykz0/

```css
h1{
    color: #df5e54;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-align: center;

    background: #df5e54;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #f2e4d7;
}
```

```html
<h1> Headline </h1>
```

But as you can see the background of the headline is going through the whole screen. What do I have to do to make it look like in the picture?

Answer (score 0):

as i understand from your question, the problems are not the horizontal lines but the background of the heading so there are a number of ways to do this

**1.** use `display:inline-block` and wrap `h1` inside a `div` with `text-align:center`

```css
h1{
 color: #df5e54;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;

 background: #df5e54;
 padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 color: #f2e4d7;
  display:inline-block;
}
div {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>
Headline
</h1>
</div>
```

**2.** wrap the text inside the `h1` in a `span` and apply CSS styles to it

```css
h1{
 color: #df5e54;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;


 
 color: #f2e4d7;
  
}
h1 span {
   background: #df5e54;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
<span>Headline</span>
</h1>
```

**P.S.** *The solution depends of the rest of your HTML structure.*

Answer (score 0):

If `flexbox` is an option you can do this:

1. Use a wrapper and give it `display: flex`
2. Create the lines using *psuedo* elements
3. `align-items:center` takes care of the vertical alignment while `justify-content: center` takes care of the horizontal alignment
4. `flex: 1` given to the *lines* makes the line take *all the whitespace* left after the `h1`

See demo below:

```css
h1 {
  color: #df5e54;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  background: #df5e54;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #f2e4d7;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #F2E4D7;
}
.wrapper:after,
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <h1>
Headline
</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: @Insane just curious, could you please respond on the answer(s) here and let us know your thoughts? maybe you can upvote if this answer helped you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
.text-holder {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
 color: #df5e54;
  margin: 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
 background: #df5e54;
 padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
 color: #f2e4d7;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.text-holder:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #df5e54;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-holder">
  <h1>
    Headline
  </h1>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```css
    h1{
 color: #df5e54;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 font-weight: 300;
 text-align: center;
position:relative;
 background:#F2E4D7;
 
 color: #f2e4d7;
}
h1 span:first-child{
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
 border-radius: 20px;
  background: #df5e54;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
h1 span:nth-of-type(2){
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  border-top:1px solid #df5e54;
  height:1px;
  width:100%;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<h1>
<span>Headline</span>
<span>&nbsp;</span>
</h1>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bv68ykz0/5/)